# Nodemailer fails to send email to outlook address

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, mern

I am trying to use nodemailer using my Gmail address. It works when an email is sent to Gmail address but when I try to send mail to any Outlook address, it gets lost in the matrix. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "gmail",
        auth: {
            user: "Mysendergmail", // generated ethereal user
            pass: "password", // generated ethereal password
        }
    });
    transporter.sendMail({
        from: '"service@onlineshop" <Mysendergmail>', // sender address
        to: "myoutlookreciever", // list of receivers
        subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
        text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
        html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
    },(err,info)=>{
        if(err){
            res.status(400).json(err)
        }
        else res.status(200).json("sent email")
    });
```